# JPA - Multiple columns discriminator

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have 3 tables like this in MySQL 5:

```
|               PERSON                     |
|  id   |  fullName  | isEmp  |  isParent  |


|      EMPLOYEE        |
|  personId   |  code  |


|       PARENT         |
|  personId   |  job   |
```

in which, `Employee.personId` and `Parent.personId` are foreign keys pointing to `Person.id`. An employee can also be a parent and vice versa. So how can I config using Annotation of JPA 2.0/Hibernate 3? Thanks!

Comment: Before thinking in JPA/Hibernate, tell us how are you supposed to describe the inheritance relationships in Java.  The relationship you are talking on is messy to me, and unable to represent in Java (or even common OO language):  Employee is-a Person, Parent is-a Person, Employee is-a Parent, Parent is-a Employee ?....

Comment: What did you try so far? What is `job`? It looks like `PARENT` would be a join table - joining with what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a Person can be both, you can't solve this through inheritance, because Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. So you'll have to go with Aggregation, which is confusing on a semantic level, because it's has-a-parent instead of is-a-parent. But I'm afraid it's the way you'll have to go:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(optional=true)
    private Employee employee;
    @OneToOne(optional=true)
    private Parent parent;
    public boolean isParent(){return parent!=null;}
    public boolean isEmployee(){return employee!=null;}
}
@Entity
public class Employee{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee",optional=false)
    private Person person; 
}
@Entity
public class Parent{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parent",optional=false)
    private Person person; 
}
```

(getters / setters etc. omitted)